Сброс до заводских настроек после n-го количества неправильных вводов ПИН - кода
На смартфонах от Samsung такая фича зашита в систему от создателей, чего не предусмотрено на аппаратах Xiaomi.
Каким бы сложным не был ПИН система просто делает паузу перед следующей попыткой, и рано или поздно такая защита будет сломана даже если тупо вручную перебирать коды. Да, можно заменить ПИН на пароль более сложный, но каждый раз разблокировать телефон, тем более одной рукой крайне неудобно.
Можно ли как-то запилить данный патч вручную? На плеймаркете максимум что есть это блокировка приложений или смена стиля экрана блокировки.


На смартфонах от Samsung такая фича зашита в систему от создателей,

Пример видимости защиты.
Эта фича, опасна как раз для владельца и не представляющая никаких осложнений для "нашедшего" телефон. Никто не будет перебирать пины (миллион комбинаций для 6ти-значного пина, между прочим), а просто сразу сбросит тело до заводских установок.

У меня на самсунге и хиаоми 4-ех значные пины, перебрать можно в течение 1 месяца вручную. В чем опасность для владельцев? Нашедший помимо самого аппарата, если заморочиться с перебором, получит доступ к конф. информации, в том числе доступ к различным аккаунтам

Опасность в том, что забыв пин владелец потеряет важные данные. А вот "конф. данные" нафик никому не нужны чтобы тратить на это время и силы.

Перебирая пины, "нашедший" рискует быть обнаруженным через ПО поиска потеряшки - маловероятно что он станет это делать, он первым делом выключит аппарат и выбросит симку, а потом спокойно сольёт дамп ФС и будет в нём ковыряться, если оно ему очень надо. А вот владелец, забудет свой пин или дети поиграются и потеряет "всё что нажито непосильным трудом"
